# 3D ranges for specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a formula that Sums the same cell across multiple sheets in excel.

However, I only want to use sheets that are "settled" or have the prefix "Set" in their name.

I have tried using 3-d references with logical statements, but it does not appear it is supported. Suggestions?

Comment: You will need a helper column that lists the sheets.  Then you can use: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'" & F14:F15 & "'!B42")))` where F14:F15 is the list of sheets and B42 is the cell on those sheets.

Comment: What does "settled" mean in this context?

Comment: use vba maybe as easiest way...oops...until I saw Scott's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Or a little UDF:

```
Public Function SumSettledSheets(cellAddress As String) As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim total As Double

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Set", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        total = total + ws.Range(cellAddress)
    End If
Next ws

SumSettledSheets = total

End Function
```

Call like so: `=SumSettledSheets("A1")`